# Trouble using an interface whose property is an Enum

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get an NPM package, [primer.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@primer-io/checkout-web) working, which includes the following Enum and interface:

```
export declare enum CheckoutUXFlow {
    SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT = "SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT"
}
```

```
export interface SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions {
  uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT;
}
```

When I try and use this in a component:

```
import { CheckoutUXFlow } from '@primer-io/checkout-web'

const singlePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions = {
  uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT
}
```

and feed it into a method expecting a SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions interface, I receive:

```
Types of property 'uxFlow' are incompatible.
      Type 'CheckoutUXFlow' is not assignable to type 'CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT'.ts(2345)

const checkoutOptions: {
    uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow;
}
```

Why does it think I'm assigning the whole Enum to `uxFlow` and not just one of its members?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code I am able to get the error that you have posted, and I assume your case too will be something along these lines only...

```
enum CheckoutUXFlow {
    CHECKOUT = "CHECKOUT",
    MANAGE_PAYMENT_METHODS = "MANAGE_PAYMENT_METHODS",
    SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT = "SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT"
}

interface SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions {
  uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT;
}

const singlePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions = {
  uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT
}

const checkoutOptions: SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions = {
    uxFlow: CheckoutUXFlow
};
```

And the error that I see is..

```
Type 'typeof CheckoutUXFlow' is not assignable to type 'CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT'
```

The problem is, while declaring the interface `SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions`, we are declaring the type of `uxFlow` as `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT`, which will strictly accept just one value.. i.e. `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT`.  If the type of a variable is `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT`, even passing a value of `CheckoutUXFlow.CHECKOUT` or `CheckoutUXFlow.MANAGE_PAYMENT_METHODS` will be an error as the type enforces only a single valid value of `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT`.

How to work around this...

- Either change in the declaration of interface `SinglePaymentMethodCheckoutOptions` the type of the field `uxFlow` to `CheckoutUXFlow` so that other values of `CheckoutUXFlow` can also be passed
- Or, change the type of the value from which you are passing(at invocation site) to `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT`.

From a typing perspective and in an intuitive sense, type `CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT` is narrower than an enum type `CheckoutUXFlow`. And we are trying to assign a broader type into a narrower one.

`CheckoutUXFlow.SINGLE_PAYMENT_METHOD_CHECKOUT` can accept only 1 value, where as type `CheckoutUXFlow` can accept any of the three.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reproduce the issue - I'm unable to try the code until later today but will update if it works